# OpenMP: Race condition in tasks

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Given this code sample the exercise is to *parallel* the code with OpenMP using tasks. It is a set of items and we want to count those which are good.

```
int count_good (item_t* item)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (item) {
       if (is_good(item))
          n++;
       item = item->next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This is not exactly homework. It is for the prepartion of an exam. My idea is the following:

```
int count_good (item_t* item)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (item) {
       #pragma omp task
       {
       if (is_good(item))
          n++;
       }
       item = item->next;
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    return n;
}
...

int main ()
{
...
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
    count_good(some_times);
}
}
```

A problem is the `n` which is a private variable of the single thread but it could be increased by different tasks at the same time. Could this generate a race condition? Can it be avoided with `#pragma omp critical` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to explicitly declare `n` as `shared`, otherwise it would be `firstprivate` by default (since it is implicitly `private` in the enclosing context). Then in order to ensure atomic increments of `n`, you should apply the `atomic update` construct. In the end your code should look like this:

```
int count_good (item_t* item)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (item) {
       #pragma omp task shared(n)
       {
       if (is_good(item))
          #pragma omp atomic update
          n++;
       }
       item = item->next;
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    return n;
}
```

The `critical` construct has a much higher overhead than the atomic increments, at least on x86.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduction` to count "good" items. Following code will do the job for you. You may want to read [this for reduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88b1k8y5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this for traversing linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163717.aspx)

```
int nCount = 0;
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+ : nCount)
{       
    for(struct item_t *listWalk = some_items; listWalk != NULL; 
      listWalk = listWalk->next)
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            if( isGood(listWalk) ){
            nCount += 1;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```